# HTML5 Video Show custom timing on scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html5-video

When I scroll, is there a way to show custom timing, like myscreenshot below.

1. Example since this is 33 seconds video, on scroll it should show the timings below the scroll 00:03
2. My html5 code below

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <title>Custom HTML5 Video Player</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  
<div id="container"> 
  
    <h1> HTML5 Video </h1> 
  
    <div id="video_container"> 
        <video controls="true"> 
            <source src="http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/763_sammyJSIntro/trailer_test.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
            <source src="http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/763_sammyJSIntro/trailer_test.ogg" type="video/ogg"> 
              
            <!-- LINK TO FLASH FALLBACK PLAYER HERE. COULD BE EMBED OR OBJECT ELEMENT -->
        </video> 
    </div> 
  
</div>     
  
</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var video = document.getElementById("Video1");

function seek() {
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    //  Current time  
    var vTime = video.currentTime;
    var left_begin = 105; //position where you want the displayed text to begin
    var left_end = 180; // position where it is at the end
    var width = left_end - left_begin;

    $("#curTime").css({
      left:left_begin + (width * (vTime / video.duration)) + "px"
    });
    console.log( $("#curTime").offset().left);

    document.getElementById("curTime").textContent = vTime.toFixed(1);
  }, false);


}
```

```css
#curTime {
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <video id="Video1" width="320" height="240" controls onseeking="seek()">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
  <div id="curTime"></div>
```

Looks like the [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924822(v=vs.85).aspx#wheream) have the answer for you. Scroll down to "Where am I". There's a little javascript function there which get's the current time. You could then use the returned values to create your own element that would appear underneath the video and slide over along.

As for the seeking event, you can use onseeking function as per this [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_seeking).

Hope that helps.